# EasyFacebook Android SDK, crashes and won't give photos

Tags: android, facebook

Sorry for bugging you with similar questions, but I can't still figure out what's the problem. :(

Here's my code so far:

```
public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {

    GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(facebook);
    User user = new User();

    try{
        user = graphApi.getMyAccountInfo();
        //graphApi.setStatus("Hello, world!"); //update your status if logged in
    } catch(EasyFacebookError e){
        Log.d("TAG: ", e.toString());
    }

    fbLoginManager.displayToast("Hey, " + user.getFirst_name() + "! Login success!");

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try{

        Log.e("info", user.getEmail() );    /// <- this three work fine!
        Log.e("info", user.getBirthday() );
        Log.e("info", user.getGender() );

        List<Album> albList = graphApi.getAllAlbumsMy();
        // CRASHES WITH:
        // ERROR/EasyFacebookAndroid(17091): Could not parse '1324505559&__paging_token=299722003399806' into a date or time.

        List<Photo> photos = graphApi.getAllPhotosMy();
        tv.setText( String.valueOf( photos.size() ) );
        // doesn't crash, but returns "0"

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("x","ERROR!");
        }


}
```

The problem is that *List albList = graphApi.getAllAlbumsMy();* crashes and *List photos = graphApi.getAllPhotosMy();* returns 0.

What did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: You missed crash stack trace.

Comment: you mean this one? ERROR/EasyFacebookAndroid(17091): Could not parse '1324505559&__paging_token=299722003399806' into a date or time.

Comment: Kinda that's me who missed it, sorry. Seems like a bug in the library.

Comment: That would be pretty sad, if its really a bug in the library, as all in all this lib looks great, way easier then the original sdk.

Comment: NOPE, it's not a library bug :))) there is an app called "Post Ticker" made with this lib that shows photos ok. So in theory it should work. :)